# Need svn log to ouput as a latex document

Tags: svn, latex

Is there any way to have the svn log command put its output into a latex document, which could then be later added to other latex documents?

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in way to do it, but since you can get XML output from `svn log` I recommend that you start looking in that direction.

One of the first hits in Google was this link (http://blog.yeticode.co.uk/2009/04/svn-log-to-latex/), maybe can give you some ideas about how to approach this.

Comment: I actually read that article and thought that it might lead to some sort of solution, however I have very little knowledge of latex and no knowledge of xml or .xslt files.  Maybe you could provide a little more direction?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't tried this myself yet, but nevertheless I'd be interested in the final solution you use.